# Certain web sites are blocked on all Azure Virtual Windows Machines

Tags: azure

I have only tested on the east coast data center.

If you have an azure virtual machine, login to it then open any browser and attempt to go to: http://www.expedia.com

You will see the following message:

```
Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http://www.expedia.com" on this server.

Reference #18.27081160.1436970336.c0a3dfe
```

You can have a new virtual machine instance, with no browser cache or cookies what-so-ever and you will see the access denied error on expedia and several other sites. It is not a browser specific issue.

Any clue on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are Expedia has blocked access to their website from common cloud hosting providers' IP ranges. StackOverflow does this for Amazon EC2 IP addresses, for example.

Comment: Agree with this though my Azure VM in SouthEast Asia can open Expedia.com just fine.